# T-SQL to Group time interval change by date range in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, aggregate-functions, min

The original table has the column Timestamp with Interval

Interval: difference in minute between the current and previous Timestamp when sorted by Timestamp itself

```
Timestamp               Interval(InMinute)
2016-12-31 00:28:00     NULL
2016-12-31 00:29:00     1
2016-12-31 00:30:00     1
2016-12-31 00:45:00     15
2016-12-31 01:00:00     15
2016-12-31 01:15:00     15
2016-12-31 01:16:00     1
2016-12-31 01:17:00     1
2016-12-31 01:18:00     1
2016-12-31 01:19:00     1
```

I want to detect a time interval change using T-SQL and produce the output

```
StartDate                EndDate                Interval
2016-12-31 00:28:00      2016-12-31 00:30:00    1
2016-12-31 00:30:00      2016-12-31 01:15:00    15
2016-12-31 01:15:00      2016-12-31 01:19:00    1
```

I wanted to tell for how long an Interval stayed the same. The second row says that from `2016-12-31 00:30:00` to `2016-12-31 01:15:00`, the Interval stayed the same i.e. 15. But then it changed back to 1 after `2016-12-31 01:15:00`

Comment: Please add your data structure and explain logic to get your desired result

Comment: @TriV I modified the question a bit

Comment: Why you by pass `2016-12-31 00:45:00` in `TimeStamp` table?

Comment: @TriV because `2016-12-31 00:45:00` is already covered in the range `2016-12-31 00:30:00` and `2016-12-31 01:00:00`. If you notice, `2016-12-31 01:01:00` is also in the last range

Comment: Then why not `2016-12-31 00:29:00` to `2016-12-31 01:02:00`, it will include all values, because you don't have any `max interval` for range

Comment: Please try to include sample data as well formatted text instead of images.

Comment: @TriV If I go with the range `2016-12-31 00:29:00` to `2016-12-31 01:02:00` then how can I tell when the Timestamp interval changed from 1 to 15 and back again?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I tried to include both image and sample data. I am trying to format it even better

Comment: @HighAbove  What rule do you want to use when displaying the intervals?

Comment: @HighAbove Why did you choose 00:29 as the first Start Date? Why was 00:30 the End? And why is the interval 1? Then, why is 00:30 the second start date? How do we know we're supposed to skip 00:45 and have 1:00 as the end? And why is interval 15 when there are 30 seconds between them? Remember, we know nothing at all about the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on [Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171106/t-sql-to-group-time-interval-change-by-date-range-in-sql-server)

[Fiddle Link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fe1888d0a934d73de0ed9887aaf4d482)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
declare @tbl table
(datec datetime)

insert into @tbl
select '2016-12-31 00:29:00'
union all
select '2016-12-31 00:30:00'
union all
select '2016-12-31 00:45:00'
union all
select '2016-12-31 01:00:00'
union all
select '2016-12-31 01:01:00'
union all
select '2016-12-31 01:02:00'

select datec,nextdatec,datediff(MINUTE,datec,nextdatec) as diff from (
select datec,LEAD(datec) over(order by datec) as nextdatec from @tbl
) tbl
where datediff(MINUTE,datec,nextdatec) is not null
```

Comment: You're very close but if you compare my desired output and yours they are a bit different

Comment: For 2nd row in your output, ideal interval (i guess) should be 30 minutes but it is 15 minutes. Check this

select DATEDIFF(minute,'2016-12-31 00:30:00','2016-12-31 01:00:00')

Comment: I just wanted to define a range of date whenever time interval in minute changes. For example the time interval between `2016-12-31 00:30:00` and  `2016-12-31 01:00:00` has stayed the same which is 15 min. Suddenly the time interval changed to 1 from `2016-12-31 01:00:00` till the end

Comment: What i understand is ,for example if time between  2016-12-31 00:10:00 and 2016-12-31 00:25 :00 then interval should be 15 but if time between 2016-12-31 00:30:00 and 2016-12-31 01:05:00 it should not display that interval right

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
    CREATE TABLE ##T1 (DATE_STAMP DATETIME)

INSERT INTO ##T1 VALUES  ('12-31-2016 00:29:00')
INSERT INTO ##T1 VALUES  ('12-31-2016 00:30:00')
INSERT INTO ##T1 VALUES  ('12-31-2016 00:45:00')
INSERT INTO ##T1 VALUES  ('12-31-2016 01:00:00')
INSERT INTO ##T1 VALUES  ('12-31-2016 01:01:00')
INSERT INTO ##T1 VALUES  ('12-31-2016 01:02:00')

 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE_STAMP) ID, * INTO ##T2 FROM ##T1

 SELECT  A.DATE_STAMP START_DATE
         ,B.DATE_STAMP END_DATE
         ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, A.DATE_STAMP, B.DATE_STAMP) INTERVAL
 FROM ##T2 A 
      INNER JOIN ##T2 B 
         ON B.ID = A.ID + 1

DROP TABLE ##T1, ##T2
```

Comment: Don't forget to Endex it lol. You have the same result as @Manish Kumar.

Comment: `select * into..` :-\